# How to receive post data(XML) in .NET like java servlet doPost

Tags: c#, xml, http, post, webserver

I want to receive the HTTP POST data(XML), the XML data post by other webServer(Tomcat, shttpd).

On Java I can use servlet doPost receive post data, I'm a newbie on C#, I don't know how to write it on c#.

Answer (score 2):

In `.NET`, network data communications is covered by [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx).

> **Windows Communication Foundation**
>
> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is Microsoft’s unified programming model for building service-oriented applications. It enables developers to build secure, reliable, transacted solutions that integrate across platforms and inter-operate with existing investments.

For information on consuming Web Services, see [Building Windows Communication Foundation Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730825.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple receive post data use System.Net.HttpListener Class, but this only receive once and exit programming.

How can I recive more.

Thinks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

/*
 * By: Bian Jiang
 * Blog: http://wifihack.net
 * 
 */

public class SimpleLinsstener
{

    public static void ShowRequestData(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        if (!request.HasEntityBody)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No client data was sent with the request.");
            return;
        }
        System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);
        if (request.ContentType != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client data content type {0}", request.ContentType);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Client data content length {0}", request.ContentLength64);

        Console.WriteLine("Start of client data:");
        // Convert the data to a string and display it on the console.
        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine("End of client data:");
        body.Close();
        reader.Close();
        // If you are finished with the request, it should be closed also.
    }


    // This example requires the System and System.Net namespaces.
    public static void SimpleListenerExample(string prefixes)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
            return;
        }
        // URI prefixes are required,
        // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // Create a listener.
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // Add the prefixes.
        //foreach (string s in prefixes)
        //{
        listener.Prefixes.Add(prefixes);
        //}
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        ShowRequestData(request);


        // Obtain a response object.
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // Construct a response.
        string responseString = "ok";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // You must close the output stream.
        output.Close();

        listener.Stop();
    }


    static void Main()
    {
        // Write to console
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the C# Station Tutorial!");
        string[] strUserNames = new String[1] {"http://*:8080/Receive/" };
        SimpleListenerExample("http://*:8080/Receive/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{
   listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        ShowRequestData(request);


        // Obtain a response object.
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // Construct a response.
        string responseString = "ok";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // You must close the output stream.
        output.Close();

        listener.Stop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See "[Walkthrough: Creating a Synchronous HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx)".